# NeoPixel setPixelColor works only in for loop

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, neopixel

I am working with a NeoPixel RGB led and have gone through various tutorials but I have a question regarding the `setPixelColor()`.

If I do not have my `setPixelColor()` and `show()` inside of a `for` loop it will not work.

This works:

```
void holoLight(uint32_t c){
  for(uint16_t i = 0; i<2; i++){
    holo_pxl.setPixelColor(i, c);
    holo_pxl.show();
    delay(2500);
  }
}
```

This does not:

```
void holoLight(uint32_t c){
    holo_pxl.setPixelColor(1, c);
    holo_pxl.show();
    delay(2500);
}
```

I am sure it is something specific to the language or execution but would love some clarifications, thanks =)

Comment: Please edit question and say what happens -- ie what colors appear, which lights turn on or off -- rather than ambiguous "works" and "not work" descriptions.  Also, to do the same thing in the second version as the first (except for delays) add `holo_pxl.setPixelColor(0, c);` and report results.

Comment: Please show the part of the code that initializes `holo_pxl` and describes your neopixel device better (is it a matrix? how many LEDs does it have?)

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried `holo_pxl.setPixelColor(0, c);`instead of `holo_pxl.setPixelColor(1, c);` in the second example?

Comment: @jfpoilpret you were spot on, I can't believe I skipped something so simple.  Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your exact problem but you have to be aware that `holo_pxl.setPixelColor(1, c);` set the color of the **second** LED in a NeoPixel chain, **NOT the first one**.

For the first LED, you have to use `holo_pxl.setPixelColor(0, c);` instead.

Comment: #facepalm...it would be something so simple. I switched out an 8 led neopixel stick for a single rgb neopixel...and didnt think about it being zero-based index. As embarrassing as this post is I will leave up for anyone else that overlooks the obvious coding late into the night o.O